# What is this symbol, showing a wavy line crossed by an arrow?

Tags: electrical

What is the following electrical symbol, used in the EU?

[image: Wavy line, crossed by arrow]

From here:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know whether the EU assigns a special meaning to that symbol but the wavy line means "AC power" and the diagonal arrow means "adjustable" or "variable". So, given this is a wireless switch, that output is the switched hot line. The outer "N" and "L" terminals are the neutral and hot supply connections, respectively, and the inner "N" is the neutral output connection.

Comment: I would like to believe you, but I saw this in the installation documentation for a wireless wall switch where it says nothing about the switch being intended for use with a dimmer.  I have updated the question with the picture of the documentation. Thanks.

Comment: @Sabuncu: OK well in this case it probably means "switched". As in, that is the controlled AC output of the device. The "N" ones are neutral and the "L" one is the constant input AC voltage (line).

Comment: I should have supplied the additional information up front, my fault.  If you could replace your answer with your comment above, I will accept it. Thanks again.